# Intersecting a result set with a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have two tables.

The first one is `people`, it has three columns (`id`, `name`, `age`).

The second one is for people group, it has three columns (`group_id`, `person_id`).

First I have a query to get people whose age is greater equal than 18:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE age >= 18;
```

Now I want to get a group which contains ALL this people. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all the above 18 years olds in one group?  Well, let's count them and see if the numbers match:

```
select pg.group_id
from people_group pg join
     people p
     on pg.person_id = p.id and p.age >= 18
group by pg.group_id
having count(distinct pg.person_id) = (select count(*) from people where age >= 18);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
select pg.group_id
from people_group pg
left join people p on p.id = pg.person_id and p.age >= 18
group by pg.group_id
having sum(case when p.id is null then 1 end) is null
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d2ed6/1)